# Erro ao usar TempData no ASP.NET 5: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou precisando usar o `TempData` numa aplicação web porém dá o seguinte erro em *runtime*:

```
InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
em Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
```

Vi em alguns fóruns que preciso habilitar alguma coisa mas não entendi direto o que. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Este é meu *controller* `Home`:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Contato contato)
    {
        SendEmail EnviarEmail = new SendEmail();

        try
        {

            EnviarEmail.EnviarEmail(contato);

            TempData["Mensagem"] = "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Erro ao enviar email!";
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Esse é meu index.cshtml

```
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">


            @if (TempData["Mensagem"] != null)
            {
                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                    var texto = "@TempData["Mensagem"]";
                    alert(texto)

                </script>
            }
            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Insira o seu nome')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
            </div>

            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Insira um email válido')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
            </div>

            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
                <input id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" type="text" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Insira um assunto')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
            </div>

            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('A mensagem é obrigatória')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input class="botao_enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

Meu site é um site de uma única pagina onde eu navego entre as sessões, por isso coloco esse `if` no `cshtml` para ver se o `TempData` está nulo e como é um redirecionamento para a mesma pagina uso ele.

Comment: Você está usando Owin?

Comment: Não cara, pra ser sincero nunca usei

Comment: Sempre usei TempData no ASP.NET mas agora no 5 tá com essa novidade

Comment: Tá, espera aí. Você está usando ASP.NET MVC 5 ou ASP.NET **CORE** (que antigamente era chamado de ASP.NET 5, ou vNext)?

Comment: Agora nesse projeto estou usando o ASP.NET 5 Web Aplication, tanto é que ainda consigo usar as tags do 5 no .cshtml

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu código? Como está fazendo para utilizar o `TempData`?

Comment: Então é ASP.NET CORE, não MVC 5

Comment: Eu to meio perdido nessas versões do ASP.NET, toda vez que eu preciso instalar o visual studio é um padrão diferente, estava usando o ASP.NET 5 tanto é que as tags são padrão ASP.NET 5 por exempo asp-controller=""

Comment: Consegui resolver seguindo esse link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0

Comment: Tive que adicionar duas linhas no project.json mais algumas linhas no Startup.cs, mas não entendi o por que disso

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema seja outro. De uma olhada se voce tem o pacote Microsoft.AspNet.Session referenciado.

Apos isso, confira a ordem o Startup.cs:

```
// Add MVC services to the services container.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddCaching(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
services.AddSession();
```

e tambem

```
// IMPORTANT: This session call MUST go before UseMvc()
app.UseSession();

// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
    // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
});
```

fonte: http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/